# Groovy - json - find parent by child property

Tags: json, groovy

Please tell me how to find the root json element in groovy
JSON available

```
{
"mom": [{"height": 1, "weight": 2}],
"dad": [{"height": 2, "weight": 3}]
}
```

you need to find an object whose height field = 2 (in this case, it's dad) and get the weight value from it (in this case, it's 3)
thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using groovy `find`, it could be something like,

```
def json = ...

def res = json.find { _,v ->
    v.find { a -> 
        a.height == 2
    }
}

println res
```